JavaScript nested AJAX calls and promises how to chain correctly?
I am stuck at setting the proper order of execution for following. Suppose, i need to make an AJAX call, then process the data and store it in IndexedDB. I use idb-keyval lib for that, which operated on promises. Then, based on the data content, i need to make another AJAX call to get some dependent data and also store it in IndexedDB. Then, i have to trigger final data processing for the document. For that I try to use ajaxStop event, which would trigger when all AJAX calls are completed. However, the order of the processing is not as expected. The ajaxStop event fires when the main AJAX call is finished without waiting for the child call to complete. Then, it fires again when sub-call is completed.
Here is my code:
import { set } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/idb-keyval@6/+esm';

$(document).on("ajaxStop", function() {
    console.log("All Done!");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/json/',
      async: true,
      beforeSend: function(){
        console.log("Sending main request!");
      },
      success: function () {
        set('test', 'test').then(() => {
            $.ajax({
              url: '/echo/json/',
              async: true,
              beforeSend: function(){
                console.log("Sending sub-request!");
              },
              success: function() {
                set('sub-test', 'sub-test');
                console.log("Sub-request done!");
              }
          });
        });
      }
    });
});

what i see in console is following:

What am I missing to make ajaxStop wait for all calls to complete? Or, how to make the main AJAX call to wait for success function to process all the data and only then report completion?

doesn't $.ajax() also have a .then method available? coz, that's how promises are chained

https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/how-to-get-out-of-promise-hell-8c20e0ab0513

First, I would replace $.ajax with fetch. Then, you can use async/await instead of the legacy callback API. I don't know any reason to use jQuery nowadays.

@jabaa some folks still have to support ancient browsers. Particularly if you do business in China.

@JaredSmith Even if you want to support jQuery, you don't have to use $.ajax. fetch and promises are more than 10 years old.

@jabaa that's what I'm trying to tell you: there are places still in 2024 where you have to support IE, sometimes even specific old versions of IE, especially if you do business in China. If you are in that position and already have jQuery for DOM manipulations or collection iteration or whatever why would you use a fetch polyfill over $.ajax? Now granted, maybe OP is not in that position and should just scrap this in favor of 4 lines of modern JS, I'm just saying we can't assume that they can.

Thanks! i got the idea, will try to refactor the code. The full case is a bit trickier as there is also forEach loop, but let's see

Your code should be changed to approximately the following:
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/json/',
      beforeSend: function(){
        console.log("Sending main request!");
      },
    }).then(() => {
      return set('test', 'test');
    }).then(() => {
      return $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        beforeSend: function(){
          console.log("Sending sub-request!");
        },
      });
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("Sub-request done!");
      return set('sub-test', 'sub-test');
    }).catch(console.error);
});

A few things to note:

You don't need to set async to true in your $.ajax requests, that's the default
Make sure you return the promises from your .then handlers to get proper timing on the chain
Don't forget to attach a catch handler, even if it's just console.error as I've done here.

